# Multiple functions in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can i create multiples functions inside for loop?

```
var mySound1 = new buzz.sound( "laser-01", { formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "acc" ]});
var mySound2 = new buzz.sound( "alien-noise-01", {formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "acc" ]});

var sound = [mySound1, mySound2]

// additional sounds
var $i;
for ( $i = 0; $i< sound.length; $i++){
    function playsound[$i](){   
           a[$i].play().fadeIn().loop();
        }
}

playsound1();
```

Comment: what is `a` ? do you mean `sound[$i]` ?

Comment: Function names have to be an identifier, so that syntax won't work at all. Also, because all those hypothetical functions will share the same variable `$i`, they won't do what you need.  This is a variation on a question asked thousands of times on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off just passing $i as a parameter to the playsound function

```
var sounds = [
    new buzz.sound( "laser-01", { formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "acc" ]}),
    new buzz.sound( "alien-noise-01", {formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "acc" ]})
];

var playsound = function (i) {   
   sounds[i].play().fadeIn().loop();
}

playsound(1);
```

And if you really want the `playsound1()` style function name, you could eval it (though I suggest against adding this):

```
for (var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++){
    eval('var playsound' + (i+1) + ' = function() { playsound(' + i + '); };');
}

playsound1();
playsound2();
```

Comment: Cheers @max for the checkmark.  I want to reiterate that I think you should use Yanick's answer below.  It's not exactly what  you wanted, but it's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can re-use a function :

```
// declare your sound dictionary
var sounds = {
    'laser':       new buzz.sound( "laser-01", { formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "acc" ]}),
    'alien-noise': new buzz.sound( "alien-noise-01", {formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "acc" ]})
};

// this is the helper function
var playSoundFn = function() {
    this.play().fadeIn().loop();
};

// assign the helper function to all your sounds
for (var i=0, len=sounds.length; i<len; i++){
    sounds[i].playSound = playSoundFn;
}


// then play your sounds from any of them in your dictionary :
sounds['laser'].playSound();
sounds['alien-noise'].playSound();
```

** **Edit** ** (thanks to [TheSmose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838763/thesmose))

If each item in the `sounds` array are created with the `buzz.sound.prototype` prototype, then you can simply add a custom function to it and simply use it :

```
// this is the helper function
buzz.sound.prototype.playSound = function() {
    this.play().fadeIn().loop();
};

// declare your sound dictionary
var sounds = {
    'laser':       new buzz.sound("laser-01", { formats: ["ogg", "mp3", "acc"]}),
    'alien-noise': new buzz.sound("alien-noise-01", {formats: ["ogg", "mp3", "acc"]})
};

// then play your sounds from any of them in your dictionary :
sounds['laser'].playSound();
sounds['alien-noise'].playSound();
```

Comment: Upvoting this... it's a good suggestion, even though it's not exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: I looked at the problem, and this is the solution that would work, instead of creating a different function for each sound. I could have given a solution to his problem, but this is better, IMO :)

Comment: Better just to define your function as `buzz.sound.prototype.playSound = function() { this.play().fadeIn().loop(); }` before the `var sounds` declaration, no?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I gave you an upvote.  It's a more graceful solution than what he requested.  Try using my suggestion above to simplify it.

Comment: @TheSmose, yes, perhaps you are right :) but then again, is `new buzz.sound` actually returning an object with `buzz.sound.prototype` prototype?

Comment: @TheSmose, I added your edits. Without more information, I think my original suggestion is also a good one.